# Insert a multiline text in column-mode in Vim

Tags: vim

I want to insert a column of text copied from a spreadsheet into a text file in column mode, so that I can visually compare two results.
For example if i have a file like:

```
status = 1
status = 0
status = 2
status = 4
```

I want to insert the reference results

```
1
-1
2
4
```

so that I get:

```
status = 1  1
status = 0  -1
status = 2  2
status = 4  4
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, with visual block mode.
It may not be the best solution, but you could do the following:

go to the last char on the line `status = 1`, start visual block `<C-v>` mark all 4 lines (`3j`) press `<S-a>` and space twice. now you have:

```
 status = 1~~
 status = 0~~
 status = 2~~
 status = 4~~
```

(`~` means trailing whitespace here).
Copy now the text you want to insert in visual block mode (`<C-v>`, mark everything, `y`).
Now mark the 4 rightmost trailing whitespaces (the position where you want to copy to)  also with visual block mode, and hit `p`

Comment: Nope, that just inserts it after the 4 lines.

Comment: Then it wasn't yanked in visual block mode, but linebased.

Answer (score 4):

Visual block is the way to go, but you have to do some trick. You copied text(column) from spreadsheet, that means, you have text with many line breaks in vim's `+` register. And the regtype would be `V` : linewise.

You have two ways to achieve you wanted:

way 1: first `"+p`, paste the column to vim, and using `visual-block` (ctrl-v) select and yank it again, and also in visual block selection, paste to your destination.

way 2: call `:call setreg('+',@+,'b')` to change the regtype to block-wise. then you can paste in visal-block mode.

I prefer way 2.

Comment: Way 3: Use my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355); it has a `gbp` mapping to force blockwise pastes.

Comment: way 2 is a wonderful addition to my solution. New for me, thank you very much, that is a very elegant solution!

Comment: I have found another thread on this topic with more good information 
[here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10608/7339)